# Symbols bug in urlencode, PHP

Tags: php, html

I am currently writing a parser for html file generated from doc files. The strings contains symbols like alpha beta etc... the problem is when I do a `urldecode(urlencode(alpha));` its not giving the symbol.. it returns something else.

To find my problem just check

```
urldecode("%0A%20%20If%20%3Ci%20style%3D%22mso-bidi-font-style%3Anormal%22%3E%CE%B1%3C%2Fi%3E%2C%20b%2C%20g%0A%20%20be%20the%20zeroes%20of%20the%20polynomial%20%3Ci%20style%3D%22mso-bidi-font-style%3Anormal%22%3Eax%3C%2Fi%3E%3Csup%3E3%3C%2Fsup%3E%0A%20%20%2B%20b%3Ci%20style%3D%22mso-bidi-font-style%3Anormal%22%3Ex%3C%2Fi%3E%3Csup%3E2%3C%2Fsup%3E%20%2B%20c%3Ci%20style%3D%22mso-bidi-font-style%3Anormal%22%3Ex%3C%2Fi%3E%20%2B%20d%2C%20the%20the%20value%20of%20%3Ci%20style%3D%22mso-bidi-font-style%3Anormal%22%3E%26nbsp%3B%CE%B1%3C%2Fi%3Eb%20%2B%20bg%20%2B%20g%3Ci%20style%3D%22mso-bidi-font-style%3Anormal%22%3E%20%CE%B1%3C%2Fi%3E%26nbsp%3B%20is%0A%20%20");
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Yes? What appears to be the problem? http://codepad.org/ogymDijK

Comment: Just run the function which is mentioned above. You can find that there are some junk characters which replace the alpha symbol.

Comment: As demonstrated in the above link, no I do not find that. Likely you're just interpreting the result using the wrong character set. Which charset are you using?

Comment: When I execute the above my output is

If Î±, b, g be the zeroes of the polynomial ax3 + bx2 + cx + d, the the value of  Î±b + bg + g Î±  is

So the alpha is replaced by something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a character set mismatch. The symbol is likely decoded to UTF-8, but you are interpreting the site as something else, likely Latin-1. To confirm that, choose UTF-8 from your browser's View > Encoding menu. Set an appropriate [header](http://php.net/header) so the site is always interpreted using UTF-8:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

This means you also need to make sure the rest of your site is valid UTF-8, or otherwise match the encoding of your text.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely UTF-8. `%CE%B1` from the urlencoded string is α (lowercase alpha) in UTF-8.

Answer (score -1):

```
You can used javascript function  unescape($urlfordecode);
Its decode your url, if you want to mannually check then used following url
```

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Use the following code for php

```
  $urlfordecode ="Your encoded url place here";

    $a = explode('&', $urlfordecode);
    $i = 0;
    while ($i < count($a)) {
        $b = explode('=', $a[$i]);
        echo 'Your decoded url is  =>  </br>',htmlspecialchars(urldecode($b[0])), 
        htmlspecialchars(@urldecode($b[1])), "<br />\n";
        $i++;
    }
```